# Powershell CSV Import loop

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to use Powershell to create a dhcpd.leases file for an ISC DHCP Server. I have imported an array in the variable $lease_import and have run the following code.

Beware; This code is not pretty (at all) and does not intend to be. (It is a one time use type of deal)

```
$input_file= Get-InputFile
$lease_import = ipcsv -Path $file_path -Delimiter "," | where { 
    ($_.binding_state -ne "ABANDONED") -and ($_.mac_address -ne "") -and ($_.ends -match "2014") 
}

$output_file = $($input_file | Split-Path) + "\dhcpd.leases"
if (Test-Path $output_file){
    ri $output_file
} 

ac $output_file "# The format of this file is documented in the dhcpd.leases(5) manual page.`n# This lease file was written by isc-dhcp-4.2.4-P2`n"
$end_time = $($(Get-Date).AddDays(7).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') +" "+ $(Get-Date -Format T) -replace "-","/")
$lease_import | foreach {
    ac $output_file "lease $($_.ip_address) {`n  starts $($($($_.starts -replace ".......$","00") -replace "T"," ") -replace "-","/");`n  ends $end_time;`n  hardware ethernet $($_.mac_address);`n  binding state active;`n}`n"
}
ac $output_file 'server-duid "\000\001\000\001\025\034G\301\000\000^\000\001\002";'
```

Running this code will generate a statement as follows:

```
lease 10.116.3.9 {
  starts 2014/10/31 09:59:00;
  ends 2014/11/09 17:01:21;
  hardware ethernet 00:1c:c4:96:bc:50;
  binding state active;
}
```

For each row in the array. Problems occur after running this script. Every statement as shown above occurs **twice** in dhcpd.leases. I have looked over this piece of code for hours on end but I can't figure out why this is happening. The imported CSV file does **not** have cloned rows. Each row is unique.

Am I overlooking something ?

EDIT: The above code would work when importing it into a DHCP server as double entries simply get applied twice, but I'd really like to figure out why they occur twice in dhcpd.leases in the first place.

Comment: Does `Get-InputFile` just get a file path? Could we have some sample input from `$file_path` to play with?

Comment: Get-InputFile is a simple function to get a file path indeed. I'll add it to the opening post. I can supply some data, but I'll have to generalize as it is company data.